# convert tree array structure to associative array with extra field in each array for breadcrumb

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

My table structure is like this:

---

### id | category | parent |

[See image of table for categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6n8J.jpg)

My Modal code:

`public function getData($table)
{
    return $this->db->select('*')->get($table)->result_array();
}`

I get an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Mobile Phones
            [parent] => 0
            [date] => 2017-05-16 08:55:22
            [slug] => mobile-phones
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Samsung
            [parent] => 1
            [date] => 2017-05-16 08:55:29
            [slug] => samsung
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Apple
            [parent] => 1
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:07:56
            [slug] => apple
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Huawei
            [parent] => 1
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:08:10
            [slug] => huawei
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => HTC
            [parent] => 1
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:08:22
            [slug] => htc
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => OnePlus
            [parent] => 1
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:08:33
            [slug] => oneplus
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => LG
            [parent] => 1
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:08:44
            [slug] => lg
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => BlackBerry
            [parent] => 1
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:08:55
            [slug] => blackberry
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => Motorola
            [parent] => 1
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:09:14
            [slug] => motorola
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [name] => Google
            [parent] => 1
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:09:52
            [slug] => google
        )
    )
```

But I want to get an array like below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [id] => 1
            [name] => Mobile Phones
            [parent] => 0
            [date] => 2017-05-16 08:55:22
            [slug] => mobile-phones
            [root_category] => null
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Samsung
            [parent] => 1
            [date] => 2017-05-16 08:55:29
            [slug] => samsung
            [root_category] => Mobile Phones

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => android
            [parent] => 2
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:07:56
            [slug] => android
            [root_category] => Mobile Phones > Samsung

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Huawei
            [parent] => 3
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:08:10
            [slug] => huawei
            [root_category] => Mobile Phones > Samsung > android
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => HTC
            [parent] => 1
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:08:22
            [slug] => htc
            [root_category] => Mobile Phones
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => OnePlus
            [parent] => 1
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:08:33
            [slug] => oneplus
            [root_category] => Mobile Phones 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => LG
            [parent] => 1
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:08:44
            [slug] => lg
            [root_category] => Mobile Phones 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => Men Fashion
            [parent] => 0
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:08:55
            [slug] => men-fashion
            [root_category] => null
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => shirt
            [parent] => 8
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:09:14
            [slug] => shirt
            [root_category] => Men fashion
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [name] => T shirt
            [parent] => 9
            [date] => 2017-05-16 18:09:52
            [slug] => google
            [root_category] => Men Fashion > shirt
        )
}
```

I'm using codeigniter by the way.

Comment: what is the desired output ?

Comment: above array is my desired output. After fetching categories from database I get an associative array same as above without root_category key I want  root_category associated and sorted as tree

Comment: Edit the question and include the code used to get the result array you show.

Comment: show your model code as well and what you've tried so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a good practice to make the Hierarchy from database logic.

The database table structure is already good enough to store the parent.

You need to have a function to call it recursively.

If your objective is to create breadcrumb, I assume you will need from the lowest hierarchy climbing up until the `parent` value is = 0.

```
function display_sub($id=0)
{
    $breadcrumb = [];

    // I assume your these are your model and function name.
    $category = $this->item_model->get_category($id);

    if($category['parent'] != 0)
    {

        // if parent not 0, add the name to $breadcrumb array,
        // then do another run of this function 
        // but take this menu's parent id as parameter
        array_push($breadcrumb,$row['name']);
        $this->display_sub($row['parent']);

    } else {

        // if parent already 0, it's finish the job.
        // and you can reverse it and display as intended.
        return $breadcrumb;
    }
}
```